# Sequelize can update data with !value, but fails to update with boolean value

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I recently started learning MySQL and get a little problem.

First:

```
words.findByPk(req.params.id)
  .then(word => {
    return word.update({
      test: !word.dataValues.test
    })
  })
```

Second:

```
words.findByPk(req.params.id)
  .then(word => {
    word.dataValues.test
     ? word.dataValues.test = false
     : word.dataValues.test = true
    return word.update({
      test: word.dataValues.test
    })
  })
```

I don't know why the first way works to update the repository and the second fails. Using "console.log" results are true or false.

Comment: Consider setting a different variable than `word.dataValues.test`? Or better yet, return with the exact value instead? e.g. `test: false`

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, it works smoothly after I run a new test, but when the judgment of the second way exists, subsequent updates fail. Maybe prototype chain is removed.

Comment: Use `set` method instead of directly assigning prop values in `dataValues`